# Datatables toggle empty data

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

I haven't found what I'm looking for via Google search, hoping for SO help.

Looking to toggle DataTables results to weed out those columns with empty data.  Currently using the search() api to filter based on each column.  I want a checkbox in each column to say "exclude empty results" based on what is contained in a particular column.  Something like "exclude blanks" so that if a row doesn't have a cellphone number, it will be excluded from the results.  Then when they unclick it, return to regular search based on what is contained in each column's search box.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SearchBuilder has built-in filters for "empty" and "not empty". Click on the ["Add Condition"](https://datatables.net/blog/2020-09-01) button to see a demo.

Comment: If that does not meet your needs, maybe you can provide a [mre] - if only to show a runnable DataTable with some suitable data, and any attempt you have already tried? You can also refer to [this DataTables forum discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/54598/column-search-blank-values) for the logic, which could be triggered by your column checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew James, I was unaware of this feature and it will work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by AndrewJames is the accepted answer.